# Multiple validations on single object?

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

scalaz Validations have `+++` which accumlates both errors and successes. However my success type isn't a `F[T]` with `Semigroup[F]`, it's just `T` (unless I use the `Id` semigroup...). Basically I want to accumulate errors only. Is there such a method?

i.e. I have a `List[A => ValidationNel[Err, A]]`, and I want to apply all these functions to a single `A` and get `ValidationNel[Err, A]`.

Comment: question needs more types

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options. If you have the validations as a list, then:

```
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

val result: ValidationNel[Err, A] =
  validations.traverse(_(a)).map(Function.const(a))
```

will get you there. However if you have the validations named, then you might get more readable code with `*>` (or `<*` depending on preference):

```
import scalaz.syntax.applicative._

validateName(a) *> validateOther1(a) *> validateOther2(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll need a couple of statements:

- One can append instances of types that form a Semigroup using `|+|` operator.
- Every applicative has a semigroup instance if it's parameter type has a semigroup instance.
- `ValidationNel[E,A]` has an applicative instance (type parameter: `A`).
- Function1: `X => A` has an applicative instance (type parameter: `A`).

So if we have several variables of type `ValidationNel[E,A]`, and A has a semigroup, then we can append them like this:

```
val result: ValidationNel[E,A] = validationResult1 |+|
                                 validationResult2 |+|
                                 validationResult3
```

On the other side, if we have a couple of functions of type `A => ValidationNel[E,A]`, we can append them as well (because `ValidationNel[E,A]` has a semigroup). If we substitute `A` with `String`, it might look like:

```
val isNonEmpty: String => ValidationNel[String,String] =
  str => Validation.liftNel(str)(_.isEmpty, "String is empty")
val max10Characters: String => ValidationNel[String,String] =
  str => Validation.liftNel(str)(_.length > 10, "More than 10 characters")
val startsWithUpper: String => ValidationNel[String,String] =
  str => Validation.liftNel(str)(_.headOption.exists(!_.isUpper), "Doesn't start with capital")

val validateEverything: String => ValidationNel[String,String] =
  isNonEmpty |+| max10Characters |+| startsWithUpper
```

Or in case of a list we can use `suml` function that has a reference on implicit Semigroup instance (this is equivalent):

```
val validateEverything: String => ValidationNel[String,String] =
  NonEmptyList(isNonEmpty, max10Characters, startsWithUpper).suml
```

The only problem is that default semigroup for most inward type parameter (`String`) is string concatenation (see `scalaz.std.StringInstances.stringInstance#append`) and in case when `A` is an arbitrary type, there might be no semigroup instance at all. We need to provide one, and in our case "take the first value" semigroup will work just fine:

```
implicit val takeFirst: Semigroup[A] = (a1: A, a2: Any) => a1
```

All above combined gives us this full test code:

```
import org.scalatest.{FreeSpec, Matchers}
import scalaz.{NonEmptyList, Semigroup, Validation, ValidationNel}
import scalaz.syntax.semigroup._
import scalaz.syntax.validation._
import scalaz.syntax.foldable1._
import scalaz.std.AllInstances.function1Semigroup

class ValidationSpec extends FreeSpec with Matchers {
  "accumulate validations" in {
    type A  = String
    type VF = A => ValidationNel[String, A]
    implicit val takeFirst: Semigroup[A] = (f1: A, f2: Any) => f1

    val isNonEmpty: VF =
      str => Validation.liftNel(str)(_.isEmpty, "String is empty")
    val max10Characters: VF =
      str => Validation.liftNel(str)(_.length > 10, "More than 10 characters")
    val startsWithUpper: VF =
      str => Validation.liftNel(str)(_.headOption.exists(!_.isUpper), "Doesn't start with capital")

    val allValidations = isNonEmpty |+| max10Characters |+| startsWithUpper
    allValidations("") shouldBe NonEmptyList("String is empty").failure
    allValidations("c") shouldBe NonEmptyList("Doesn't start with capital").failure
    allValidations("c2345678901") shouldBe NonEmptyList("More than 10 characters", "Doesn't start with capital").failure
    allValidations("Good value") shouldBe "Good value".successNel

    val listValidations  = NonEmptyList(isNonEmpty, max10Characters, startsWithUpper)
    val foldedValidation = listValidations.suml1
    foldedValidation("") shouldBe NonEmptyList("String is empty").failure
    foldedValidation("c") shouldBe NonEmptyList("Doesn't start with capital").failure
    foldedValidation("c2345678901") shouldBe NonEmptyList("More than 10 characters", "Doesn't start with capital").failure
    foldedValidation("Good value") shouldBe "Good value".successNel
  }
}
```